# Python3 Django GCloud Connectors local development has Python2 dependency

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, djangae

I am upgrading a Django project on Google App Engine from Python 2.7 to Python 3.10 runtime. It works well in production, but local development does not work. When running `python manage.py runserver` the local server starts up just fine, but on sending a request that accesses the local datastore, the following error is shown:

(NOTE: dependencies are installed into `sitepackages/dev/` and `sitepackages/prod/`, which are added to PATH during runtime)

```
ERROR    2023-10-12 10:56:46,886 [exception:88] Could not import googledatastore. This library must be installed with version >= 6.0.0 to use the Cloud Datastore API.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/app_name/team/models.py", line 68, in get_or_create
    team = key.get()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 606, in get
    return self.get_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 615, in get_async
    ctx = tasklets.get_context()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1160, in get_context
    ctx = make_default_context()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1202, in make_default_context
    return _make_cloud_datastore_context(datastore_app_id, additional_apps)
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 1232, in _make_cloud_datastore_context
    raise datastore_errors.BadArgumentError(
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadArgumentError: Could not import googledatastore. This library must be installed with version >= 6.0.0 to use the Cloud Datastore API.
```

Installing the `googledatastore==7.0.2` dependency and running `python manage.py runserver` again:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/user_name/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/app_name/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import ndb
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.ndb.tasklets import *
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 105, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import datastore
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 63, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import datastore_types
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 58, in <module>
    from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_pbs
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/prod/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_pbs.py", line 55, in <module>
    import googledatastore
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/dev/googledatastore/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import helper
  File "/home/user_name/backend.worktrees/Python3/project_name/sitepackages/dev/googledatastore/helper.py", line 406
    _MICROS_PER_SECOND = 1000000L
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python310
app_engine_apis: true
entrypoint: gunicorn project_name.wsgi:application -b :$PORT -w 8 -t 600

instance_class: F4

handlers:

- url: /internal/.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  login: optional

- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

requirements.txt:

```
django-cors-headers==4.2.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
Pillow==10.0.0
line-bot-sdk==3.1.0
requests-toolbelt==0.10.1
qrcode==7.4.2
xmltodict==0.13.0
icecream==2.1.3
google-cloud-logging==3.5.0
google-cloud-storage==2.10.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.16.2
more_itertools==9.1.0
elasticsearch==7.17.9
elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.1
chardet==5.1.0
djangae==2.0.0rc2
django-gcloud-connectors==0.4.0
django==3.2.20
django-csp==3.7
django-session-csrf==0.7.1
six==1.16.0
# legacy bundled services for python3
appengine-python-standard==1.1.2
# web server (entrypoint)
gunicorn==20.1.0
# temporary fix for build error: AttributeError: cython_sources
# similar issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/8036
pyyaml==5.3.1
```

What should I do to make local development work in Python 3?

Comment: You mentioned writing to the local datastore, do you mean you're using the datastore emulator? Do you write to the datastore using the bundled service APIs (legacy services)?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I do believe Django GCloud Connectors uses the datastore emulator under the hood because its documentation page mentions using the Cloud Datastore API. And yes, we do use legacy bundled services, which is why we have the `appengine-python-standard` dependency.

Comment: The codebase uses native NDB syntax, and does not (directly) use Google Cloud NDB/Google Cloud Datastore.